# insertion sort using 2 arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to figure out how to use insertion sort to sort an array of ints. I need to take values from the original array and put them into the new array. I will show what code I have, but I have hit a brick wall and cannot figure out how this sorting method works.`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int[] orgArray = {5,4,1,6,3,144,2,14};
    int[] newArray = new int[orgArray.length];
    int currentNum=0;
    for(int x=1; x<orgArray.length; x++)
    {
        if(x==1)
            newArray[0]=orgArray[0];
        else
            for(int y=x;y>0; y--)
            {
                currentNum = orgArray[x];
                if(newArray[y]<currentNum)
                {
                    for(int z=orgArray.length-2;z>y;z--)
                        newArray[z]=newArray[z+1];
                    newArray[x]=orgArray[x];
                }

            }
    }
    System.out.println("Ascending order : " + Arrays.toString(newArray));
}
```

The output is:

```
Ascending order : [5, 0, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14]
```

Comment: I did this in python the other day, even that was a pain :/

Comment: Do you have to use two arrays?

Comment: Apparently last year's class got this program easily, but for me, this was a 3 day program until @Elliot_Frisch helped out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking at [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), first consider the algorithm -

[image: Insertion sort animation example]

From the animation, you should be able to tell that it's in-place. With that in mind, I think you wanted something like this -

```
int[] orgArray = { 5, 4, 1, 6, 3, 144, 2, 14 };
int[] newArray = new int[orgArray.length];
// Copy the original array.
System.arraycopy(orgArray, 0, newArray, 0,
    orgArray.length);
for (int x = 1; x < newArray.length; x++) {
  int currentNum = newArray[x]; // <-- the current number changes on every loop
  int y = x;

  // The actual condition on which to shift up!
  for (; y > 0 && newArray[y - 1] > currentNum; y--) {
    newArray[y] = newArray[y - 1];
  }
  // All shifts done, insert the correct place.
  newArray[y] = currentNum;
}
System.out.println("Ascending order : "
    + Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Which outputs,

```
Ascending order : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 14, 144]
```

Comment: I would upvote your comment, but I don't have enough reputation. I didn't know that System.arraycopy(); existed. Thanks for your help!